# Azure Devops build pipelines : build configuration in Yaml file not used

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

I have a build pipeline yaml file that looks like the following:

```
# ...

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Production 12'

# ...

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The **Production 12|Any CPU** configuration is supposed to be built.

But it is not, another one is (Test|Any CPU), as shown in the logs:

```
Starting: VSBuild
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio build
Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
Version      : 1.199.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build
==============================================================================
"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -latest -format json
"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools -latest -format json
"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\SafeProtect.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=10c69004-b8fb-410e-ba0d-6d600dac481c|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s|enableOrphanedProjectsLogs=true"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="D:\a\1\a\WebApp.zip" /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Test" /p:VisualStudioVersion="16.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_09716650-7645-4cc6-8318-3b574bba08b5_build_1_0"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Build started 3/17/2022 12:36:04 PM.
Project "D:\a\1\s\SafeProtect.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Test|Any CPU".
```

What is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by recreating the build pipeline (.yml file).
So I guess that there is a glitch while processing the .yml file when it is modified to update the pipeline tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Devops build pipelines : build configuration in Yaml file not used

First, try to check if you missing build configuration in the Configuration Properties with Visual Studio or the checkbox of build is not checked.

Right clicking the solution, selecting "Properties" and then looking at the "Configuration Properties" property sheet:

[image]

Second, try to build and deploy it on your local to check if you have this issue, if not, please check the MSBuild version (Visual Studio Version) and the  .net framework version with the version on the Azure devops.